# How to target an object in scene.scn programatically?

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I have a sphere in my scene.scn and want to target that sphere in the ViewController.swift. Can I create an outlet to that object somehow? Do I have to create a variable and set it equal to that object?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a variable and use the [childNodeWithNAme](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407951-childnode) instance function to find the desired node.

```
 let sphereNode = childNode(withName: "sphereNodeName", recursively: true)!
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 3D object in a `Scene graph` that you loaded manually and other objects and lights you made programmatically, you can easily target this object in `.scn` file.

> To make your 3D model to become accessible for virtual programmatic lights and other geometry use the following code:

```
func childNode(withName name: String, recursively: Bool) -> SCNNode? {
    return SCNNode()
}  

let geometryNode = childNode(withName: "art.scnassets/your3Dmodel", 
                             recursively: true)!

scene.rootNode.addChildNode(geometryNode)
```

Where `recursively: true` means: to search the entire child node subtree, or ***false*** to search only the node’s immediate children.